# Android ViewGroup clipping doesn't work

Tags: android, view, clipping

Why is android:clipChildren="false" not working? I want to achieve the same effect as the CSS overflow: visible so that the child views are visible even if they're positioned outside their parent layout. I tried something like this and although the Graphical Layout in Eclipse shows the correct behaviour, on the phone it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#0000FF"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is funny, but I can't on the contrary make parents to clip their children. But I have LinearLayout. Maybe that is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I'm, trying something similar for now and it works only when I use booth            `android:clipChildren="false"` on all parents a next problem is if under overlapped child is something that repaint itself like ListView, Android then forgot repaint our child and it disappear :-(

Only way is call .invalidate() manually on overlapped child after every repaint of view under it :-(
I also found that at least small peace of overlapped child must be in the its parent.

And another problem is with receive touch/click events in view which is outside of the parent. I not found any solution for it.